# How to convert my get request to post request

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with bellow script

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      start: function(){
          $("#success-result").html("loading....");
      },
      update : function () { 

          var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
        $("#success-result").load("<?php echo base_url('explorer/processSortable'); ?>?"+order);
      }
    });
```

Now I want to send request to my url with post method. How can i do it.

Comment: Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: don't mix php code inside javascript code, do something like `var url = "<?php echo base_url('explorer/processSortable'); ?>?";` on top of your js code

Answer (score 0):

Jquery load function is a shorthand method to get a content from server. By default, the POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Use $.post instead:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url('explorer/processSortable'); ?>?"+order, function( data ) {
  $( "#success-result" ).html( data );
});
```